# Preimage of maximal ideal of the homomorphism $R[x_0, ..., x_n] \to (R/M)[x_0, ..., x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain with maximal ideal $M$, and suppose $R/M$ is algebraically closed. 
Let $\phi: R[x_0, ..., x_n] \to (R/M)[x_0, ..., x_n]$ defined by taking the coefficients modulo $M$. 
What does the preimage of the maximal ideal $I = (x_0 - \beta_0  + M, ..., x_0 - \beta_n  + M)$ look like?

Is 
$$
\phi^{-1}(I) = \bigcup (x_0 - \gamma_0, ..., x_n - \gamma_n )
$$
where the union is over all $\gamma$ such that $\gamma_j - \beta_i \in M$?

Comment: I don't think your claim holds for the right hand side is not an ideal. In order to figure this out can consider the case $\beta_i=0$ for all $i$. This can also give a hint for how $\phi^{-1}(I)$ looks like. In this particular case $\phi^{-1}(I)=M+(x_0,\dots,x_n)R[x_0,\dots,x_n]$. In general, we have $\phi^{-1}(I)=M+(x_0-\beta_0,\dots,x_n-\beta_n)R[x_0,\dots,x_n]$

Comment: @user26857 If I say it's the ideal generated by what is on the right hand side, then it becomes the same as what you are saying?

Comment: Do you mean that $I$ is generated instead by the $x_i-\beta_i+M$? Otherwise $I$ isn't a maximal ideal for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: @Mindlack I was wondering if $\phi^{-1}(I)$ is the ideal generated by elements of the form $x_i - \beta_i + M$